# Specific value can not be searched by preparedStatement executeQuery() in view table

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, resultset

I tried to use executeQuery() to get the resultset from a view table but a specific values is not returned

```
    String sql = String.format( "select * from view_table where id = %s", 2161581)
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
          preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement( sql );
          ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
          while ( rs.next() ) {
            resultList.add( rs.getString( field ) );
          }
          rs.close();
          return resultList;
        }
```

The actual view table is like :

```
id
1131521
2161581
1161511
```

The resultset returns null only when id = 2161581, and I tried to use the sql query directly hit database and the record is there. This is so weird. Any thoughts for this or I missed something?

Comment: What's a `field` variable?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov it's "id"

Comment: Can you use `select id` instead of `select *` then, so there's no guessing on what the query projection would be in that case?

Comment: Still returns null, if I change to other two values it works. Not sure what's wrong with this id number

Comment: How `id` column declared in database? I suspect is not numeric type, but string of some sort.

Comment: *`String sql = String.format( "select * from view_table where id = %s", 2161581)`* Should be `String sql = "select * from view_table where id = ?";...preparedStatement.setInt(1, 2161581);`

Comment: @HenlenLee, what you've described here isn't actually possible if you defined everything correctly, because it can't return `null` for `id` when you queried it to have `id = 2161581`. You probably should look what else is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [javadoc of `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

If you are using PreparedStatements you are also supposed to enter a query with some `?` in it. You can then set the parametere(s) before you call that statement.

something like this:

```java
        String field = "id";
        String sql = "select * from view_table where id = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 2161581);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                resultList.add(rs.getString(field));
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultList;
```